# Read android assets files throw NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, robotium, android-assets

I am working on android automation test, I create a test project in eclipse. (In automation, it will be packed as apk and deploy onto emulator)
And In my project, I want to read a xml file in **assets** folder. I put my xml file "mytest.xml" directly in the folder **assets**. And I want to load it and parse. But it seems I will always get NullPointerException.
Below is my code

1.the function is defined in a class OSNCommonLib.

```
public class OSNCommonLib extends Activity {
    public  String readTranslationFile(String fileName,String transunitId) 
    {
        if(doc == null)
            {
                try
                    {
                    InputStream in = getAssets().open(fileName);
                    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
                    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder(); 
                    doc = builder.parse(in);

                    }

                    catch ( Exception e )
                    {
                        System.out.println("mytest catch" + e.toString() );
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


                org.w3c.dom.Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
                NodeList nodes = root.getElementsByTagName( "trans-unit" );
            .......
                }
                ....
    }
```

And the function above will be called in another java class

```
public class TC01_OSNdemo extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {
OSNCommonLib ocl = new OSNCommonLib();
...
public void testSortByButton(){

    ....
        String getstr = ocl.readTranslationFile("mytest","osn_menu_sortby");
        Assert.assertTrue(solo.searchText(getstr));
    ...
}
```

And in the catch, I will always get java.lang.NullPointerException.
Does it means it can't load my file? 
I tried many times and still the same errors.

Can anyone give some suggestions about this issue?

Besides: here is the full log

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.stg.osn.lib.OSNCommonLib.readTranslationFile(OSNCommonLib.java:107) --> **point to org.w3c.dom.Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();**

at com.sgt.osn.junit.test.TC01_OSNdemo.testSortByButton(TC01_OSNdemo.java:142)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1661)
```

At last, the problem is sovled. As I extend my test case on Instruments, I should use the below method to call:
InputStream in = getInstrumentation().getContext().getAssets().open("mytest.xml");
The useful link
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestCase.html
http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg62671.html

Thanks to all!!!

Comment: what is exactly null? InputStream or anything else?

Comment: use this line InputStream in = getAssets().open("mytest.xml");

Comment: also check file mytest.xml is in assest folder not in subfolder

Comment: can post log too?? would be much easier to debug..

Comment: Do not provide the extension `.xml` Just use `getResources().getAssets().open("mytest");`

Comment: The log is only in try catch statement. Just java.lang.NullPointerException. The other log is related to the function that call this function I pasted.

Comment: this code is in some class? or activity? and posting log is helpful

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar, thanks for the help. But it seems still can't work. Still the same error.

Comment: have u check xml file in assest folder not in subfolder have u added screen shot of thia

Comment: @Darpan the log is posted

Comment: @incr3diblenoob log is posted

Comment: Is there any chance you make doc(Document) variable null? Looking at http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse(java.io.InputStream), there is no reason parse method returns null document object.

Comment: Well, I made some example code. Please have look at https://github.com/sh1nj1/exercise-andy/blob/master/app/src/androidTest/java/com/sh1nj1/android/exercise/AssertReaderActivityTest.java

Comment: shows an error in OSNCommonLib.java's line 107, what is it?

Comment: Problem is solved at last, I should use InputStream in = getInstrumentation().getContext().getAssets().open("mytest.xml"); to read the file. Because my class extend Instruments Class.

Comment: @Darpan, Thanks to your comments. It give me some ideas. Thanks! The problem is solved.

Comment: @Chk0nDanger, Thanks a lot for your example code. Yes, it give me some ideas. Thanks! The problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this..

```
public String readDataFromAssets(String file) {
    try {
      InputStream is = getAssets().open(file);
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

      String line = null;
      try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          builder.append(line);
          // builder.append("\n"); // append a new line
        }
      } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
        try {
          is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

      return builder.toString();      

    } catch (IOException e) {

      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the file using the `R`-object. This would mean that you put your XML-file in the RAW-folder. Then you can access the file by simply writing

> InputStream inputStream =
>   activity.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mytest);